# Ad Hoc iOS Distribution Profiles become invalid

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, beta, profiles

When the profiles become invalid, the beta version that was distributed with that profiles in active could be used in normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't worry about those builds, which were distrubuted earlier.
Here is an official Apple distribution guide:

> A provisioning profile appears invalid if it contains a revoked or
>   expired certificate.

Expired certificates:

> Certificate expiration or revocation
>
> For standard developer program
>   teams (those whose distribution method is the iOS App Store),
>   expiration or revocation of a code signing certificate does not affect
>   any apps that were signed with that certificate (this includes
>   development builds, beta test builds, and live App Store apps). Its
>   just an indication that the profile must be regenerated/updated to be
>   associated with a new, valid certificate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1878/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want you to help me look at this condition.

Comment: I export my archive in the way "save for Ad Hoc Deployment", and it success to become a package. Yesterday, the package can be installed in my iPhone, and works normally. but today when I tap the logo, the app crashed . So I uninstall the app ,and install the package again. But I can't install the package,it prompt me "you can't install the app in this time". I break down. So, I log in my developer, and find that the profile has become invalid.So I guess when the profile become invalid, the package using the profile can't be used in normal. What do you think?

Comment: I find the apple doc that explain the suitation. While the profile become invalid, the beta version also will become invalid. That is the apple explanation, and I believe it.